# Simulating multi-touch events (one finger linear swipe)

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am doing an edit to a driver file that uses [Multi-Touch protocol](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt). 
My goal is to bind a swipe gesture from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) that follows a line.

To do this i execute this function inside the key pressure detection function:

```
static void do_swipe(struct kp *kp, long xstart, long ystart, long xend, long yend,
        int id) {
    printk("SWIPE! X1 %d Y1 %d X2 %d Y2 %d ID %d \n",xstart,ystart,xend,yend,id);
    int sx, sy;
    int dx = abs(xend - xstart);
    int dy = abs(yend - ystart);
    if (xstart < xend)
        sx = 1;
    else
        sx = -1;
    if (ystart < yend)
        sy = 1;
    else
        sy = -1;
    int err = dx - dy;
    long tempx = xstart;
    long tempy = ystart;
    while (1) {
        key_report(kp, tempx, tempy, id);
        //Touch is now detected with input_sync
        input_sync(kp->input);
        if(tempx == xend && tempy == yend) break;
        int e2 = 2 * err;
        if (e2 > (-1)*dy) {
            err = err - dy;
            tempx = tempx + sx;
        } else if (e2 < dx) {
            err = err + dx;
            tempy = tempy + sy;
        }
    }
    printk("END! X %d Y %d \n",tempx, tempy);

}
```

This function is an edited Bresenham's line algorhitm that instead of drawing a line calls key_report to simulate a touch at the given coordinates.

```
static void key_report(struct kp *kp, long x, long y, int id) {
    if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        //printk("---------- zero point --------------\n");
        ;
    } else {
        input_report_key(kp->input, BTN_TOUCH, 1);
        input_report_abs(kp->input, ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID, id);
        input_report_abs(kp->input, ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR, 20);
        input_report_abs(kp->input, ABS_MT_WIDTH_MAJOR, 20);
        input_report_abs(kp->input, ABS_MT_POSITION_X, x);
        input_report_abs(kp->input, ABS_MT_POSITION_Y, y);
        input_mt_sync(kp->input);
    }
    release = 1;
}
```

Where kp-> input is so defined

```
struct input_dev *input;
```

**Edit:** I updated the code and I'm also attaching the generic code of a key pressure, because I'd like the driver to perform a swipe only once for each key pressure, to avoid swipe looping.

```
static void kp_work(struct kp *kp) {
int i, code, value;
kp_search_key(kp);
if (key_param[0] == 3) {
    if (kp->key_valid[4] == 1) {
        value = kp->key_value[4];
        kp->flagchan4 = 0;
        if (value >= 0 && value <= (9 + 40)) {
            if (key_param[99] == 1 ) {
                do_swipe(kp, key_param[25], key_param[26], key_param[97],
                        key_param[98], 12);
            } else
                key_report(kp, key_param[25], key_param[26], 12);
        } else if (value >= 392 - 40 && value <= (392 + 40)) {
            if (key_param[102] == 1) {
                do_swipe(kp, key_param[23], key_param[24], key_param[100],
                        key_param[101], 12);
            } else
                key_report(kp, key_param[23], key_param[24], 12);
        } 
        kp->flagchan4 = 0;
    } else {
        kp->flagchan4 = 1;
    }
}
input_sync(kp->input);
}
```

Maybe i could set a check on kp->flagchan4... 
**Edit:** Setting a check on flagchan4 did the trick.

Comment: As in [this document](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt), it seems to say that you need a final `input_sync()` to flush them out.  You also might try to put the code in a `work_queue`, I don't know if the event system is getting swamped with values.

Comment: @artlessnoise you gave me the right hint and now i put an input_sync right after every `key_report`. Now touch events are shown on the screen, but if i keep pressed the key the swipe continues, how to implement a strategy to "lock" the key so that it performs only one swipe?

Comment: @artlessnoise driver is working thanks to your hint. If you want to create an answer I'll accept it

Comment: It is fine to create a community wiki answer and accept it; or you can just create your own if you really crave points.  I would update your title to "Simulating multi-touch events".  I think this describes what is going on better.  If I edit a question and change the meaning, a bunch of non-kernel developers reject it.